# How do i make this into a struct?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, multidimensional-array

OK so I have erased everything trying to make this into a struct, because i messed it up bad.

I need this code of arrays to become a struct.

```
FILE *pFile;
    int choice = 0;
    char buf[40];


    int id[sizeof(buf)];
    char name[sizeof(buf)][20];
    char state[sizeof(buf)][5];
    char dis_code[sizeof(buf)];
    float balance[sizeof(buf)];
    char due_date[sizeof(buf)][40];
```

This is what I got do so far but when i try to use it it goes nuts. I still don't know how to load the file into it.

```
struct fileinfo
{
    int id[10];
    char name[20];
    char state[5];
    char dis_code[5];
    float balance[10];
    char due_date[40];
} info[sizeof(buf)];
```

Am i missing something or do i have the right idea. The problem is when i run this the same why i would the regular arrays I run into errors.

Comment: What errors do u get ?(or we should guess it?)

Comment: mostly am i am asking am i building the struct right.

Comment: Or what is the right way to make that array into a struct. Because i think that is my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is your only issue, but you have changed the type of several of the fields.

```
int id[sizeof(buf)];        // id[i] is an int
char dis_code[sizeof(buf)]; // dis_code[i] is a char
float balance[sizeof(buf)]; // balance[i] is a float

struct fileinfo
{
    int id[10];             // info[i].id is an _array of 10 ints_
    char dis_code[5];       // info[i].dis_code is an _array of 5 chars_
    float balance[10];      // info[i].balance is an _array of 10 floats_
} info[sizeof(buf)];
```

An array of a type and single instance of that type will behave quite differently.

I would suggest making the fields of the struct the same type as your original array elements, i.e.:

```
struct fileinfo
{
    int id;
    char dis_code;
    float balance;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since  you declared `char buf[40]` ==> `sizeof(buf) = 40`. You are changing the 2 dimensional array into a single dimensional. The structure should be like

```
   struct fileinfo
   {             
     int id[40];
     char name[40][20];
     char state[40][5];
     char dis_code[40];
     float balance[40];
     char due_date[40][40];
    }
```